# Sparql BIND result of count WITH A VARIABLE

Tags: sparql

Is there any way to **bind** the result of **count** to a variable?  I've tried the following (which doesn't work):

```sql
SELECT ?totalSubject WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o
  BIND(COUNT(?s) AS ?totalSubject)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`COUNT` is an [aggregate](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates) function and may be used only to define projected variables. To count all matches, your specific example should read:

```sql
SELECT ( COUNT(?s) AS ?totalSubject ) WHERE {

    ?s ?p ?o. 

}
```

However, aggregate functions are usually applied to [groups](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#groupby) of matches. For instance, to count subjects grouped by type:

```sql
SELECT ?t ( COUNT(?s) AS ?totalSubject ) WHERE {

     ?s a ?t.

} GROUP BY ?t
```

Be aware that when using aggregate functions your query is subject to some [restrictions](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregateRestrictions): selected variables must be either

- simple variables included in `GROUP BY`; or
- aggregates or constant values.

Comment: sorry i did not get the idea. what is i and ii  in your answer ?

Comment: Just numbered items in a list. Edited for clarity.